# Skip read statement to printf statement

Tags: c

Why it prints hello then good luck then again hello before reading from socket `sockfd` ?
so why it skip read to print?

```
int number=read(sockfd,&buff,500);
while(number>0)
{
printf("hello ");
number=read(sockfd,&buff,500);
printf("good luck");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when connected to a terminal, `stdout` is line buffered, add a `\n` to the end of the print content like `prinf("hello\n");` or use `fflush`:

```
while(number>0)
{
    printf("hello ");
    fflush(stdout);
    number=read(sockfd,&buff,500);
    printf("good luck");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: Yu Hao he need FILE argument .. :\

Comment: I used both the "\n" and the fflush() bus still problem not solved yet >.<......... thank you so much

Comment: @user2849082 Then you need to be more specific about the problem, a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) is preferred.

Comment: the code works fine before adding the sub code

Comment: I am Sorry to be not specific ,But I figured out the problem was with the "/n" for the data which comes when reading from buffer by read(), how to remove it ?

Comment: @user2849082 You mean the `buff` you get contains `\n` that you want to remove? You can iterate over the string and replace `\n` with `\0`.

Comment: the data on the socket It goes right when I read from buffer twice ^_^
thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Change this read statement

```
number=read(sockfd,&buff,500); ==> number=read(sockfd,buff,500);
```

You just need to read into buffer.

Comment: even so not worked .... this code is part of larger code .. is there any chance to be another reason?

Comment: You are assuming buff is `char*` or something similar. What if it is a struct with size larger than 500 bytes?